# CNN layers confusion

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have this model which is attempting to classify cats and dogs:

```
model = Sequential([Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
                    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                    Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
                    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                    Flatten(),
                    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(2, activation='softmax')]) # pick between 2 different possible outputs

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

and then attempting to run the model like so:

```
history = model.fit(x=train_data_gen, steps_per_epoch=total_train//batch_size, 
                    epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=val_data_gen,
                    validation_steps=total_val//batch_size)
```

however, I get this ValueError:

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1)).
```

If I change the last dense layer to have a dimensionality of 1, then this runs, but I want a binary classification with 2 output layers to which I softmax between them to analyze the testing data.
How do I fix my `train_data_gen` in order to match the dimensionality, as it is  a `keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator` object defined like so:

```
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                     directory=train_dir,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     class_mode='binary')
```

Is there a way I can reshape this object so my model runs correctly, because I can't seem to find it with regards to this object, or if I need to convert this into a numpy array or tensor first. Also, how do I classify dimensionality/filter arguments in these models? I went with 128, 64, 32, and cutting by 2 because this is what I saw online, but if an explanation could be provided as to why these values are picked that would greatly help me out. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use the binary classification `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` with `binary_crossentropy` loss? Technically, if you're using `Dense(2, activation='softmax')` you should probably be using `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss function, but don't see any reason to not just use `sigmoid` + `binary_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jay Mody for your response. I was away on holiday and taking a break from this project, but yes what you suggested was correct and useful to actually understand what I was doing. I also wanted to mention a few other errors I had which led to a worse/useless model performance.

The `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` arguments were not totally incorrect, but produced weird graphs that I didn't see in other online examples
[image]

I learned how they are implemented through this [website](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-set-steps-per-epoch-with-keras/#:%7E:text=In%20Keras%20model%2C%20steps_per_epoch%20is,reduce%20simultaneously%20and%20vice-versa.), in my case substituting the training images and validation images counts as the corresponding sizes. Now my graph looks like so:

[image]

Also I played around with my filter(s) arguments for my model, and found this [resource](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/deep-learning-tutorial/guide-to-building-powerful-keras-image-classification-models) helpful. My model now looks like so, and works well:

```
model = Sequential([Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
                    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                    Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
                    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
                    Flatten(),
                    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
                    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')]) # pick between 2 different possible outputs




model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Hope this helps others, this whole field still confuses me but we go on :)